# How to catch a fatalError caused by during a UITest?

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

The UITest in question launches the app, taps a cell which pushes the Screen to be tested and then fails with a fatalError() when i make a change that i expect will call a fatalError().

How can i catch the fatalError on the UITest and use it to report that the UITest has failed?

Here is the UITest:

```
class ConcreteFoodScreenUITests: XCTestCase
{
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app.launch()
    }
    func testPathToConcreteFoodScreen() throws {
        //Tap Concrete Cell in FoodDashboard to go to the ConcreteFoodScreen
        XCTAssertTrue(app.otherElements["FoodDashboard"].exists)
        app.scrollViews.otherElements.tables.staticTexts["100 g, 100cal, P: 90g, F: 80g, C: 70g"].tap()

        //ConcreteFoodScreen
        XCTAssertTrue(app.otherElements["ConcreteFoodScreen"].exists)
        app.tables.cells.containing(.staticText, identifier:"Scale").children(matching: .textField).element.tap()
        app.keys["5"].tap()  //FIXME: Crashes with a Fatal Error

    }
}
```

Here is the code that is being triggered that i want to know about:

```
class ScaleCellTextField: SWDecimalTextField {

    //there is more code here but not relevant

    func updateFoodEntry() {
        fatalError()
//        if let scale = Double(self.text!) {
//            concreteFood.scale = scale
//        }
    }
}
```

You can see that i commented out some code here to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. `FatalError()` ends your app's process, so I'm not sure you can catch this kind of event.

**EDIT**:

But...

You can use our dear good old Darwin Notifications... In order to add create a communication channel between your apps : the tested app and the tester app.

You'll need to add a file to both your targets:

```
typealias NotificationHandler = () -> Void

enum DarwinNotification : String {
    case fatalError
}

class DarwinNotificationCenter {
    let center: CFNotificationCenter
    let prefix: String
    var handlers = [String:NotificationHandler]()

    init(prefix: String = "com.stackoverflow.answer.") {
        center = CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter()
        self.prefix = prefix
    }

    var unsafeSelf: UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
        return Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
    }

    deinit {
        CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver(center, unsafeSelf, nil, nil)
    }

    func notificationName(for identifier: String) -> CFNotificationName {
        let name = prefix + identifier
        return CFNotificationName(name as CFString)
    }

    func identifierFrom(name: String) -> String {
        if let index = name.range(of: prefix)?.upperBound {
            return String(name[index...])
        }
        else {
            return name
        }
    }

    func handleNotification(name: String) {
        let identifier = identifierFrom(name: name)
        if let handler = handlers[identifier] {
            handler()
        }
    }

    func postNotification(for identifier: String) {
        let name = notificationName(for: identifier)
        CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(center, name, nil, nil, true)
    }

    func registerHandler(for identifier: String, handler: @escaping NotificationHandler) {
        handlers[identifier] = handler
        let name = notificationName(for: identifier)
        CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center,
                                        unsafeSelf,
                                        { (_, observer, name, _, _) in
                                            if let observer = observer, let name = name {
                                                let mySelf = Unmanaged<DarwinNotificationCenter>.fromOpaque(observer).takeUnretainedValue()
                                                mySelf.handleNotification(name: name.rawValue as String)
                                            }
        },
                                        name.rawValue,
                                        nil,
                                        .deliverImmediately)
    }

    func unregisterHandler(for identifier: String) {
        handlers[identifier] = nil
        CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver(center, unsafeSelf, notificationName(for: identifier), nil)
    }
}

extension DarwinNotificationCenter {
    func postNotification(for identifier: DarwinNotification) {
        postNotification(for: identifier.rawValue)
    }

    func registerHandler(for identifier: DarwinNotification, handler: @escaping NotificationHandler) {
        registerHandler(for: identifier.rawValue, handler: handler)
    }

    func unregisterHandler(for identifier: DarwinNotification) {
        unregisterHandler(for: identifier.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Then, simply, in your tested application:

```
@IBAction func onTap(_ sender: Any) {
    // ... Do what you need to do, and instead of calling fatalError() 
    DarwinNotificationCenter().postNotification(for: .fatalError)
}
```

To catch it in your test, just do the following:

```
// This is the variable you'll update when notified
var fatalErrorOccurred = false

// We need a dispatch group to wait for the notification to be caught
let waitingFatalGroup = DispatchGroup()
waitingFatalGroup.enter()

let darwinCenter = DarwinNotificationCenter()

// Register the notification
darwinCenter.registerHandler(for: .fatalError) {
    // Update the local variable
    fatalErrorOccurred = true
    // Let the dispatch group you're done
    waitingFatalGroup.leave()
}

// Don't forget to unregister 
defer {
    darwinCenter.unregisterHandler(for: .fatalError)
}

// Perform you tests, here just a tap
app.buttons["BUTTON"].tap()

// Wait for the group the be left or to time out in 3 seconds
let _ = waitingFatalGroup.wait(timeout: .now() + 3)

// Check on the variable to know whether the notification has been received
XCTAssert(fatalErrorOccurred)
```

And that's it...

**Disclaimer**: You should not use testing code within your production code, so the use of DarwinNotification should not appear in production. Usually I use compilation directive to only have it in my code in debug or tests, not in release mode.

Comment: I think you *could* register a mach signal handler to catch it, but yeah, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: I don't think that it is a *signal* that can be caught (but I may be wrong of course).

Comment: is there another kind of event i could catch? maybe throwing an error?

Comment: You can't catch an exception, because the tests are running in another app than the tested app. The only thing you can do is via the user interface : display an error for the user and let your test check if the error is displayed. You can also use Darwin Notifications (only when testing) to send messages between apps. Usually you use it from your tests to trigger something in your app, but you can also use it from your app and be caught in your tests.

Comment: I've added an example on how to use Darwin Notifications to achieve what you're looking for. If you agree, don't forget to vote up and accept my answer.